# when function finish (including the setTimeout(s)) call function

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

Hi I have an ajax call with this function inside:

```
for(var i in data){
    setTimeout((function(i) {
         return function(){
            CreateMarker(data[i]);
         };
     })(i), i*500);
    }
```

It adds markers in a google map, using `google.maps.Animation.DROP`.
I need that when all markers are in the map, the drop animation change to: `setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)`, I know how to change the animations.

Here is my problem:
I know when the ajax ended but because of the timeout I can't know when all the markers have been "dropped" into the map, so I don't change the animation early.

Any idea of how can I do to know when all the markers are placed in the map so I can change the animation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to add another `setTimeout` after your for:

```
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){ // assuming data is a contiguous array
  setTimeout((function(i) {
    return function(){
      CreateMarker(data[i]);
    };
  })(i), i*500);
}
setTimeout(changeAnimation, (i-1)*500);
```

The `changeAnimation` function will be executed right after the last CreateMarker.

---

I find that when things are repeating periodically, it can help a lot to replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval`:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var markerData = data.shift(); // changes data, use a copy if you want to use data anywhere else
  if (markerData) CreateMarker(markerData);
  else { clearInterval(interval); changeAnimation() }
}, 500);
```

In this simple version `changeAnimation` will be executed 500ms after the CreateMarker call, but it can be changed easily to execute immediately after:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var markerData = data.shift();
  CreateMarker(markerData);
  if (!data.length){ clearInterval(interval); changeAnimation() }
}, 500);
```

Comment: I used the first solution, easy, smart and low impact in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a variable to count the placed markers and check if you are done after each.

```
var done = 0;

for(var i in data){
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() {
            CreateMarker(data[i]);
            if (++done == data.length) {
                // execute code here
            }
        };
    })(i), i*500);
}
```

Here is a working example of the code with random data: http://jsfiddle.net/S3LQK/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a count of the timers so you can tell when the last one has fired.

Since you don't show what type of variable `data` is, this solution will work whether `data` is an array or an object (though you generally shouldn't iterate arrays with `for (var i in data)` so I assumed it was an object.

```
var timerCntr = 0;
for(var i in data){
    ++timerCntr;
    setTimeout((function(i) {
         return function(){
            CreateMarker(data[i]);
            if (--timerCntr === 0) {
                // last timer is done now
            }
         };
     })(i), i*500);
}
```